# Parse JSON and select a specific key in python

Tags: python, json, parsing, jsonparser

I'm trying to select a specific key in this code which is the 163, 203 & 13. Basically, each time, my function runs, I'll have one of these 3 codes stock in a variable and I can't figure out how to parse a specific element in a Json file. I'd like to make a loop who stops for example at the key '203' and return me the result of it.

```
with open('data.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    for key, value in data.items():
        id = '203'
        id_value = value['payload']['price']
        pack = id_value[id]
        print(pack) #pack should be returning the value of the key '203'
```

Here's the JSON. The JSON is divided in 3 parts, each part starts with a random key, that I don't know and, if you look on the JSON, after the payload, there is the price and then the id (e.g. '203'). I need to get the value of this id.

```
{
  "a506b5686": {
    "status": {
      "message": "Ok",
      "code": 0,
      "user": {
        "isBanned": false,
        "isNotConfirmed": false
      }
    },
    "payload": {
      "vat": 0,
      "price": {
        "163": {
          "100": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 16.54,
            "shipment_price": 2.31,
            "quantity": 100,
            "batchsize_id": 60348
          },
          "200": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 23.17,
            "shipment_price": 2.31,
            "quantity": 200,
            "batchsize_id": 60354
          },
          "300": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 28.29,
            "shipment_price": 2.31,
            "quantity": 300,
            "batchsize_id": 60360
          },
          "400": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 34.11,
            "shipment_price": 2.31,
            "quantity": 400,
            "batchsize_id": 60366
          },
          "500": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 39.33,
            "shipment_price": 2.31,
            "quantity": 500,
            "batchsize_id": 60372
          },
          "600": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 44.04,
            "shipment_price": 2.95,
            "quantity": 600,
            "batchsize_id": 60378
          },
          "700": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 48.32,
            "shipment_price": 2.95,
            "quantity": 700,
            "batchsize_id": 60384
          },
          "800": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 52.22,
            "shipment_price": 2.95,
            "quantity": 800,
            "batchsize_id": 60390
          },
          "900": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 55.79,
            "shipment_price": 2.95,
            "quantity": 900,
            "batchsize_id": 60396
          },
          "1000": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 59.07,
            "shipment_price": 2.95,
            "quantity": 1000,
            "batchsize_id": 60402
          },
          "maxDeliveryDays": 6,
          "minDeliveryDays": 4
        }
      },
      "maxDeliveryDays": 6,
      "minDeliveryDays": 4,
      "productionCountry": [
        "CN"
      ]
    },
    "pager": {
      "total": null,
      "current": 1,
      "count": null
    }
  },
  "a28bb008b": {
    "status": {
      "message": "Ok",
      "code": 0,
      "user": {
        "isBanned": false,
        "isNotConfirmed": false
      }
    },
    "payload": {
      "vat": 0,
      "price": {
        "203": {
          "100": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 16.21,
            "shipment_price": 2.31,
            "quantity": 100,
            "batchsize_id": 60972
          },
          "200": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 22.58,
            "shipment_price": 2.31,
            "quantity": 200,
            "batchsize_id": 60978
          },
          "300": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 27.5,
            "shipment_price": 2.31,
            "quantity": 300,
            "batchsize_id": 60984
          },
          "400": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 33.11,
            "shipment_price": 2.31,
            "quantity": 400,
            "batchsize_id": 60990
          },
          "500": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 38.14,
            "shipment_price": 2.31,
            "quantity": 500,
            "batchsize_id": 60996
          },
          "600": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 42.69,
            "shipment_price": 2.31,
            "quantity": 600,
            "batchsize_id": 61002
          },
          "700": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 46.82,
            "shipment_price": 2.95,
            "quantity": 700,
            "batchsize_id": 61008
          },
          "800": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 50.58,
            "shipment_price": 2.95,
            "quantity": 800,
            "batchsize_id": 61014
          },
          "900": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 54.02,
            "shipment_price": 2.95,
            "quantity": 900,
            "batchsize_id": 61020
          },
          "1000": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 57.18,
            "shipment_price": 2.95,
            "quantity": 1000,
            "batchsize_id": 61026
          },
          "maxDeliveryDays": 6,
          "minDeliveryDays": 4
        }
      },
      "maxDeliveryDays": 6,
      "minDeliveryDays": 4,
      "productionCountry": [
        "CN"
      ]
    },
    "pager": {
      "total": null,
      "current": 1,
      "count": null
    }
  },
  "a2e2a89bf": {
    "status": {
      "message": "Ok",
      "code": 0,
      "user": {
        "isBanned": false,
        "isNotConfirmed": false
      }
    },
    "payload": {
      "vat": 0,
      "price": {
        "13": {
          "100": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 14.95,
            "shipment_price": 2.31,
            "quantity": 100,
            "batchsize_id": 58240
          },
          "200": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 20.37,
            "shipment_price": 2.31,
            "quantity": 200,
            "batchsize_id": 58226
          },
          "300": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 24.57,
            "shipment_price": 2.31,
            "quantity": 300,
            "batchsize_id": 58237
          },
          "400": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 29.41,
            "shipment_price": 2.31,
            "quantity": 400,
            "batchsize_id": 58228
          },
          "500": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 33.76,
            "shipment_price": 2.31,
            "quantity": 500,
            "batchsize_id": 58234
          },
          "600": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 37.69,
            "shipment_price": 2.95,
            "quantity": 600,
            "batchsize_id": 58235
          },
          "700": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 41.25,
            "shipment_price": 2.95,
            "quantity": 700,
            "batchsize_id": 58264
          },
          "800": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 44.5,
            "shipment_price": 2.95,
            "quantity": 800,
            "batchsize_id": 58270
          },
          "900": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 47.46,
            "shipment_price": 2.95,
            "quantity": 900,
            "batchsize_id": 58239
          },
          "1000": {
            "country_id": "CN",
            "product_price": 50.2,
            "shipment_price": 2.95,
            "quantity": 1000,
            "batchsize_id": 58223
          },
          "maxDeliveryDays": 6,
          "minDeliveryDays": 4
        }
      },
      "maxDeliveryDays": 6,
      "minDeliveryDays": 4,
      "productionCountry": [
        "CN"
      ]
    },
    "pager": {
      "total": null,
      "current": 1,
      "count": null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate the question? can the key be present at any level in the json tree? And what exactly is that you need to be printed?

Comment: I edited, the question, is my question question clearer?

Comment: There is another key right under price, you'll have to get this one as well

Comment: Yes the key right under price, is the key I have in a variable before parsing the code and I need to get the value of this key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with checking the id it its exists before accessing it.

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

id = '203'

with open('data,json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    for key, value in data.items():
        id_value = value['payload']['price']
        if id in id_value: # check first if id is present
            pack = id_value[id]
            print(pack) #pack should be returning the value of the key '203'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('data.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    for key, value in data.items():
        id = '203'
        if value['payload']['price'] == id:
            print(value['payload']['price'])
```

This is what I could make out from your question. Comment below if that wasn't what was intended.

Comment: Thank you also! The only issue here is the "==", it should be "if id in value[..] But thank you guys !

Answer (score 0):

I tried flattening the JSON object so all the keys sit at the same level.

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('data.json') as data_file:
data = json.load(data_file, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
data=json_normalize(data)
id='163'
for key, value in data.items():
    nested_ids = key.split('.')
    if (id in nested_ids):
        print(value)
```

Does this get you in the right direction?